# How to support architecture reuse with minor differences

Tags: hardware, vhdl

I need some hints about VHDL. I'm pretty new to it so be kind.

I've written a module and I've registered the output (it's a Carry Save Adder - CSA). I've used this module in some part of my design.

Now I've to use the same module, but I need to remove the output register (I need to use that in a combinational way). I know that I could copy and paste the VHDL code and use a different entity, but in my opinion it's a little bit inelegant.

I thought to use a generic parameter, but I don't know where to start. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the solution. I can use generate statement. Is it correct ?

Comment: CSA? You could read [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Your question seems unclear. Show us the code you want to modify use declared names to reference what you want to change.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Improve your question. The version of the VHDL standard your tool supports matters in answers, it can require two generate statements one for the register and one without (-1993 has no ELSE in generate).

Comment: Sorry if i was chaotic, but actually I wasn't sure what I was asking. CSA stands for Carry Save Adder, and I've fixed using a generate statement. The VHDL is -2002 version. Thanks for the tips about the rules and sorry If I've made some mistakes.

Comment: Consider making changes to your question and answering it yourself. It may keep you from getting a down vote question block and right now you have an unclear question with no answer and no ability for someone else to answer.  Most synthesis software is -1993 syntax compliant with specific newer features.  I'd be surprise if that included `else generate` which isn't available in -2002 either. You may need two generate statements to get the output connected properly both with and without the register.

Comment: David Koontz: Personally I don't see the problem with the question. It wasn't a great title, and the language was a little inelegant and terse, but nothing a little editing couldn't fix up. The concept being asked about is a general one, and details about the internals of his module aren't necessary to answer the question, neither is the version of VHDL (just use the old style - It works everywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add a *registered output* generic to the architecture. If this is true, implement the registered output. If it's false, connect the output to what would have been the input to the register. You can then instantiate it in the two different locations with the generic set differently.

This code is completely untested (not compiled even), but hopefully you get the idea.

```
GEN_REG : if REG_OUTPUT = true generate
    p_output : process is
    begin  -- process p_output
        wait until clk'event and clk = '1';
        Q <= Q_internal;
    end process p_output;
end generate GEN_REG;

GEN_WIRE : if REG_OUTPUT = false generate
    Q <= Q_internal;
end generate GEN_WIRE;
```